# Why is this multithreading code running slower than single thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, grasshopper

[image]

Hi,

I'm  doing my first attempts at multithreading in c# within grasshopper. The function is a simple distance between two points function, with two inputs of 10,000 points. The code is working but its taking a much much longer time than a single threaded component. I'm curious if anyone could explain why this is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using Rhino;
using Rhino.Geometry;

using Grasshopper;
using Grasshopper.Kernel;
using Grasshopper.Kernel.Data;
using Grasshopper.Kernel.Types;

using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;


  private void RunScript(List<Point3d> x, List<Point3d> y, ref object A)
  {

    var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<Point3d, double>(Environment.ProcessorCount, x.Count);

    List<double> output = new List<double>();
    foreach(Point3d pt in x) results[pt] = 0;


    Parallel.ForEach(x, pt =>
      {
      results[pt] = pt.DistanceTo(y[x.IndexOf(pt)]);
      });

    foreach(Point3d pt in x)
    {
      output.Add(results[pt]);
    }

    A = output;
```

I know there must be heavy overheads with using concurrentdictionary, two loops and list but I assumed the higher the population of points, the more you would see a benefit over a single thread, which isn't the case. If I'm using a really inefficient method I'd like to know, or if for such a simple task there's little chance the overheads will ever justify multi-threading?

Comment: If `pt.DistanceTo` is just an Euclidean distance, then it's not really that much work, computationally, and the overhead of actually writing to a concurrent dictionary will be much higher, yes. But it's hard to tell without profiling. Also, please show your single threaded version.

Comment: You should probably not run every single distance calculation as an own thread but e.g. half of the calculations in one and the other half in a second thread. Or maybe partition into more parts. And let each thread populate its own dictionary and merge them all together at the end to avoid the ConcurrentDictionary bottleneck.

Comment: Hi Etienne, 
The single threaded version is basically just
    
    x.DistanceTo(y)

In grasshopper you can forgo list structures and this runs a lot quicker. How it works exactly I'm not sure, the code is blackboxed.

Klaus, thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a test to see whether things improved.

Comment: Multithreaded code only becomes faster if you run it on a multi-core computer. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: _"I know there must be heavy overheads with using concurrentdictionary,"_ - no, there is a heavy overhead of `x.IndexOf(pt)` being `O(n)` which makes your code effectively `O(n^2)` (and parallelization would not be able to solve this issue).

Comment: @Somebody I'd be surprised to find a singled threaded CPU that CAN to run .Net.

Comment: computing the distance between two points involves a few cheap adds and multiplies, and a somewhat expensive Square root. If you can, use the squared distance instead, if you need to compare something, just square the other side of the equation as well. Your current code is completely dominated by manipulating all the collections.

Comment: When I tested I found this code is by far the fastest: `Enumerable.Range(0, x.Count).Select(n => x[n].DistanceTo(y[n])).ToList()`. No threading at all. Let the single core sing!

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things you can do to optimize your code, two of which I tried with your code:

- Limit the number of threads you are using (using `ParallelOptions`). As the workload for each iteration is very small, this will limit the overhead of the parallelization.
- Use `Parallel.For` instead of `Parallel.ForEach` so you don't need to lookup the index for each point. This has nothing to do with parallelization but just reduces the workload in a dramatical manner.
- Create `output` from `result` in one go instead of adding the results one by one.

Implementing these in your method could give something like:

```
private void RunScriptOpt(List<Point3D> x, List<Point3D> y, ref List<double> A)
{
    var results = new ConcurrentDictionary<Point3D, double>(Environment.ProcessorCount, x.Count);
    List<double> output = new List<double>();
    Parallel.For(0, x.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, (i) =>
    {            
        results[x[i]] = x[i].DistanceTo(y[i]);
    });       
    
    output = results.Values.ToList();

    A = output;
}
```

Benchmarkresults for both:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Gen1 | Gen2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaiveParallel | 105,161.0 us | 2,039.82 us | 2,652.35 us | 159600.0000 | 1000.0000 | 800.0000 | 1909.71 MB |
| OptParallel | 736.1 us | 4.65 us | 4.12 us | 99.6094 | 98.6328 | 49.8047 | 1.18 MB |

Executing time is reduced to 0.7% of the original and memory allocation to 0.06% (reducing load on the garbage collector a lot).

Obviously this optimized version will compare much more favorably to the single-threaded code than the original method...

> I should clarify I'm trying to output the distances so they associate with the order of the points going in,

Accomplishing this is even more simple. You don't need a ConcurrentDictionary for this. Since each iteration will calculate and store the result completely independent from the other iterations, no synchronization is required and you can use a simple array:

```
private void RunScriptOpt(List<Point3D> x, List<Point3D> y, ref double[] A)
{
    double[] results = new double[x.Count];
    Parallel.For(0, x.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, (i) =>
    {            
        results[i] = x[i].DistanceTo(y[i]);
    });                       
    
    A = results;
}
```

Of course this will make your code still faster (and reduce the memory allocations even further):

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Gen1 | Gen2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NaiveParallel | 143,491.07 us | 9,306.979 us | 27,441.839 us | 159600.0000 | 32800.0000 | 600.0000 | 1955547.13 KB |
| OptParallel | 27.47 us | 0.203 us | 0.190 us | 6.6528 | 2.2888 | - | 81.42 KB |

Comment: Excellent suggestions. Thankyou! The reason I'm creating an output from an extra loop is because the dictionary order becomes jumbled from the input list of points, the same seems to happen with your code. But it is definitely a good chunk faster.

Comment: What di you mean by "dictionary order"? A dictionary does not have an order.

Comment: Keys in a Dictionary are not guaranteed any specific order. You could sort them when you display them. Or just _not_ use a Dictionary but an Array instead. After all, you know how many items your result vector will have. And then you'd have results in the same order as input.

Comment: @CharlesBoman if you need some order - sort data after processing it and putting it into dictionary. `Dictionary` is essentially unordered collection  and the fact that your code results in order that you need is not guaranteed and should not be relied upon.

Comment: You're both correct. I should clarify I'm trying to output the distances so they associate with the order of the points going in, which I'm assuming you guys already guessed. When I say dictionary "order" I just meant if the results are written straight from the dictionary they are jumbled from the input, so I had that extra loop to to call the distances based on the pt as a key.

Fildor, I was originally wondering about using arrays. I have yet experimented with a method of multithreading with them, but I'm guessing they would work fine with concurrentQueue?

Comment: If I'm reading into your comments correctly, a thread-safe collection class should be added to during the parallel processing not before?

Comment: @CharlesBoman: I updated my answer with a version that outputs the results in the same   order as the input-arrays (which is even simpler an more efficiënt than the original answer).

Comment: @Johan Donne You're a treasure

Comment: Great answer, but I'm really curious what the single threaded performance of your optimized version would be.

Comment: @JonasH: the same code, single threaded has a mean execution time of 156,58 µs  (6.6 times longer than the parallel version using 10 threads) and allocates 78.15kB (slightly less than the parallel version).

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that the biggest issue in the code is the use of `IndexOf` which makes your code effectively `O(n^2)` so I would start from testing out the single-threaded approach. If you think about your data manipulation happening here - you are matching incoming collection by index and computing the result, which is what the [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0) is for, so try something like (add `using System.Linq;`):

```cs
private void RunScript(List<Point3d> x, List<Point3d> y, ref object A)
{
    // if needed - check that both sequences are of the same size
    A = x.Zip(y, (l, r) => l.DistanceTo(r))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Note that [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-7.0) will produce result with size of the shortest collection:

> The method merges each element of the first sequence with an element that has the same index in the second sequence. If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them. For example, if one sequence has three elements and the other one has four, the result sequence will have only three elements.

If you have really that much items you can try using PLINQ before going deep into different kinds of optimizations:

```cs
private void RunScript(List<Point3d> x, List<Point3d> y, ref object A)
{
    // if needed - check that both sequences are of the same size
    A = x
        .AsParallel()
        .Zip(y, (l, r) => l.DistanceTo(r))
        .ToArray();
}
```

If this method is a part of critical path and you want to squeeze as much performance as possible then you can go with the 3rd option from the another answer - preallocate the resulting array of needed size and fill it (no need for concurrent collections here because there would be no contetntion/race guarantees - every read/write will for different index). Or similar (preallocate results array and use `for` loop) single-threaded approach (parallelization usually make sense either for big inputs sizes or relatively long computations performed).

P.S.

Use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) for benchmarking, but note that in general there are a lot of moving parts and same code can behave differently based on number of factors (.NET version, OS, CPU architecture ...)

Comment: Very concise explanation, I hadn't even heard of the concepts of O(n) til you wrote it. Definitely something I'll start learning, its a method I've abused in my coding in the past.

Comment: @CharlesBoman yes, this is one of the notations for algorithmic complexity, which comes in handy in such situations. Was glad to help! If any of the answers works for you - feel to mark it as accepted one (checkmark on the left).